# Ball Physics - Modifying a balls X/Y position by a rotation

Tags: c++, math, physics

I'm trying to create a pool game in openGL / C++, the way I am currently doing my cue balls movements is with a hit function that passes through a float which is a value between 0 and 360 for the rotation, and a hit velocity which is a vector,

The issue im having is modifying the cues balls movement based on the rotation, this is what im currently using, it kind of works but its giving un expected results, (o is the cue ball)

```
if (rot >= 0.0f && rot < 90.0f)
{
  Balls[0]->Hit(rot, Vector3D(1.0f, rot/100, 0.0f), deltaTime);
}

if (rot >= 90.0f && rot < 180.0f)
{
  Balls[0]->Hit(rot, Vector3D(-1.0f, -rot / 100, 0.0f), deltaTime);
}

if (rot >= 180.0f && rot < 270.0f)
{
    Balls[0]->Hit(rot, Vector3D(-1.0f, rot / 100, 0.0f), deltaTime);
}

if (rot >= 270.0f && rot < 360.0f)
{
  Balls[0]->Hit(rot, Vector3D(1.0f, rot / 100, 0.0f), deltaTime);
}
```

This is the actual function on the pool ball object:

```
void PoolBall::Hit(float hitRotation, Vector3D hitVelocity, float deltaTime)
{
    velocity.x = hitVelocity.x;
    velocity.y = hitVelocity.y;
}
```

What is the math behind for doing this properly?

Comment: /OT: Ouch, don't rotate balls :-P ...

Comment: I dont particularly want to rotate balls, they just need to move in the x and the y, for example moving just right would be 1.0f, 0.0f, moving up is 1.0f,1.0f I just need the maths for the coordinates in between when the angle of the pool cue is 45 degress, the value would be 1.0f, 0.5f, but how do i get that from 45? :P

Comment: The motion you are describing here is this the Hit on a Cue Ball from a Cue stick or is this the change in direction / velocity after the Cue Ball hits another Object Ball?

Comment: This is the motion of the cue ball being hit by the cue as if to take a shot :)

Comment: Okay thank you for the information. I'll post an answer as in a guide to what to look for, since it will consider many aspects, but before I do, is this rendering in 2D or 3D?

Comment: Thank you! this is rendering in 3D, I can post screenshots if you'd like?

Comment: Screen shots are not needed, just wanted to know which Dimensional space you are working in.

Answer (score 0):

For 3d rotations, always use quaternions. Boost has a quaternion library ( in boost/math I believe )

Comment: Whats the process of making a quaternion? I'm fairly new to collision and physics collision, I've been scripting in engines for years but have only recently been making the jump to programming engines? Thanks :)

Comment: This looks like a good introduction.http://content.gpwiki.org/index.php/OpenGL:Tutorials:Using_Quaternions_to_represent_rotation . It can look intense, but in practice the code is not bad. I'll see if I can put together some example code

Comment: Yes the math and theory of Quaternions is very hard and easy to get confused and lost in, but the code and programming of them is in some sense the same simplicity of doing vectors and basic matrices!

Comment: If you are using OpenGL with GLSL shaders then the GLM math library has quaternions defined too if I remember correctly. For DirectX their math library does!

Comment: Always using quaternions is not always a good idea in 3D physics simulation. It depends on the need. If you are rotating an object relative to only 1 axis then you can use Euler Angles. However, if you need Full Freedom of Rotation simultaneously on All 3 Axis such as the motion of a Jet's motion in a 3D Flight Simulator then Quaternions are A MUST! If a barrel is rolling on the floor Euler Angles are fine but a Rolling Ball then Quaternions are a MUST!

Comment: Agreed, @FrancisCugler I should probably soften the language and expound a bit more...

Answer (score 0):

Here are some things to consider. You have a cue ball that is the shape of a sphere, you have a cue stick that is a cylinder. In reality you have the exact position of contact on the cue ball with an applied force from the cue stick. Since your cue stick is a cylinder only the area of the circle on the tip is important, you don't have to worry about the exact shape since approximation will work, so the area of a circle will work just fine. The surface area of the Sphere that comes into contact with the area of the circle will mostly likely not change. Since the size of the cue stick is a small percentage of the contact point of the surface area on the sphere we can use a linear vector to represent the cue stick instead of the area of a circle, and we can define the the cue ball to be a unit sphere to simplify all calculations.

To do a basic collision detection in this scenario you have a ray tracing element with sphere collision, but you shouldn't have to worry about checking for collision since a hit is nearly 100%.

The angle of contact from the cue stick vector is important and should have these types of attributes associated with it: Its angle relative to the x-z plane, the angle relative to being perfectly perpendicular to the contact area on the cue ball, its directional velocity and amount of applied force. This will be the initial contact! Then you have the release contact. Is the cue stick staying on the exact trajectory or does it change direction after it hits the ball? If you are assuming that the trajectory is the same then no more work needs to be done, but if the shot is of a masse type shot, then the change in direction vector, velocity etc. needs to be accounted for.

Once the initial contact of the cue stick on the surface area of the cue ball is applied, the balls direction in most cases is proportionately related to the x-z components of the force vector if the force vector from the cue stick is very close to being parallel with the table(x-z) plane. If there is a rise in angle above or below this horizontal plane then the amount of force applied to the cue ball should be a percentage of the force vectors direction in the reflected direction, since the ball can not travel below the surface of the table's x-z plane, but it can however travel above the plane, then this motion needs to be generated by a basic gravity ball toss problem. And once the ball jumps and hits the table (x-z) plane it needs to be applied again with a dampening effect, where the dampening effect is the decrease in force or momentum in the "Y" direction, the velocity of the x or z directions will still have most of its velocity.

There is an easy way to do this. You could take the surface area of the sphere and use the area of a circle that has the same radius and you could define a 3x3 or 4x4 grid that is a plane that is tangent to the cue ball and initially is perpendicular to the cue stick vector. However you will need to define the coordinate positions of each square within the grid relative to the surface area of the sphere. The total with and height of this grid should equal the radius of the sphere. Then this way using unit circle will make your calculations much easier and efficient.  Then with this you would have sectors of the sphere's surface area that would define different behaviors of contact. So image a 3x3 grid for now to keep it simple. You would have these enumerations, that represent each grid location of the circle's area.

```
 enum SurfaceContact {
     TOP_LEFT = 0,
     TOP,
     TOP_RIGHT,
     RIGHT,
     CENTER,
     LEFT,
     BOTTOM_LEFT,
     BOTTOM,
     BOTTOM_RIGHT
  };
```

Then with this you can subdivide the calculations where the cue ball is being hit which will help to simplify the force vectors and the resulting motion of the Cue ball. You could then use this enumeration either in an if else if or a switch statement. The latter preferred. You can then pre-calculate the needed forces, angles of contact etc. and then pass them into a function that outputs the change in motion. Would look something like this:

```
Vector3 detectAndApplyPositionOfContact( const* BallObject& pCueBall, const* Vector3& directionVector, const* Vector3& forceVelocityVector, const* Vector3& incomingAngles, SurfaceContact contact ) {

    Vector3 resultingAppliedForceAndVelocityVector;

    switch( contact ) {
        case TOP_LEFT: {
            // Do Some Work According to this location on the ball
            // using the vectors passed in.
            return resultingAppliedForceAndVelocityVector = applyForce( args1, args2, ... argsN ); 

        }
        case TOP: {
            // Same As Above
        } 
        ..
        .
        .
        case BOTTOM_RIGHT: {
            // Same Concept
        }
        default: {
            // either throw error or return Vector3( 0, 0, 0 );
        }
    }
}
```

With this the work done on each sub section of the surface area of the sphere is different, so the calculations will be done before hand, then the needed parameters will be applied into the returning function that will actually apply the force to the ball to cause it to move.

Now if you actually want the ball to rotate while it is moving more work needs to be done, but I would not use Euler Angles, for you will fall into the pit of Gimbal Lock. If you want to rotate the ball as it is also projecting off of your desired trajectory then I would suggest using Quaternions. That is a little more involved and in depth then what is discussed here. But these are some of the things to take into consideration. Remember though a lot of things can be factored out when rendering 3D graphics because approximation works just fine, since you only want the "relative projected motion" of your object.

It all depends on how realistic you want the motion of the Cue Ball to appear. If you are aiming for trueness with All variations of English and Masse applied to the cue ball then even a few more elements will come into play. In this case you would still have your 3x3 grid of the sphere's surface area being represented by a circle, and in this case the grid will still be tangent to the surface of the sphere, but your cue stick vector may not be exactly perpendicular, then you would have full rotation in the x-y plane within each specific grid cell.

This is not an exact answer that will make your graphics render properly, it is a guideline of what to consider in order to generate the motion you desire, and how accurate you want the motion compared to real life physics. For example, gravity will come into play slightly if the ball is masse and the cue stick is in the TOP grid and has an angle of rotation above the horizontal z- axis along with its angle in the x direction. Here gravity has to affect the ball as it reaches its pinnacle to bring the ball back down to the table's surface. However elements of the ball such as its weight and density are negligible in rendering physics simulations.

Another thing to take into consideration is if the Cue Stick is hitting the Cue Ball in the BOTTOM_LEFT, BOTTOM, & BOTTOM_RIGHT grid cells, are you applying a backspin on the ball that is applied after the "Cue Ball" Hits an object ball, and the same with TOP_LEFT, TOP, & TOP_RIGHT that isn't masse but with a forward spin to follow the ball? There is a lot to consider when doing physics calculations and proper rending in a Pool Game!

I hope this helps as a "Guide Line" for it is not a definitive one step solution that fits all problems.

Also another thing to consider is that this 3x3 grid is only approximation if and only if the contact point is on the "Facing Side of the Cue Ball that is relative to the player's looking direction" This does not include the "Above or Top Surface area of the cue ball" You have 2 planes to work with both in a 3x3 or 4x4 grid fashion. However the same methods can be applied from the TOP of the ball, however anything from the "TOP" of the ball is MASSE. So to make this simpler you would have to have a check to see where the Cue Stick incoming trajectory is relative to the ball. Once you have this resulting normal vector from a ray tracing algorithm then you can set a flag that says isMasse true or false. If it is true then you would be working with the TOP 3x3 grid, if not then you are working with the front facing 3x3 grid. This way all motion from the facing 3x3 grid is a forward motion based on force (speed of ball) and velocity( direction ball will move in the x-z plane), where if it is the TOP 3x3 Grid then your motion will have height values based on the ball tossing algorithms.

Having these 2 3x3 grids to work with in defining which motion will result from the initial contact can be applied to anywhere on the Cue Ball. The Player's rotation around the ball does not have any effect in this fashion for all the trajectories will be the same.

Comment: The function you showed returns a reference to a stack variable. Also, its input arguments are... references to pointers? Yikes.

Comment: Constant references being passed in so their are no copies of the vectors on the stack. The values passed in are used within the scope of the function but are also persevered. The return value should of been just a vector3 not by reference. I'll fix that

Answer (score 0):

### This answer is a follow up answer and is based on the logic of when to or not to use Euler Angles versus Quaternions. And why Euler Angles behave the way they do!

In 3D physics simulations and rendering you have 3-axis X,Y,Z respectively since all 3-axis are perpendicular to each other these create 3 distinctive planes to work with and they depend on how you setup your coordinate space. We will assume that +X is to the Right, +Y is Up and +Z can either be going into the screen or coming out of the screen. The Difference between these two is a Right-Handed and a Left-Handed coordinate space. Here we have the XZ plane which is the ground or horizontal. You then have the XY & YZ planes which are vertical both can be considered Walls that are Perpendicular to each other.

---

When working with rotations in 3D and applying the transformations these are applied to your Model View Projection Matrix in which the order of multiplication matters because not every Matrix has an inverse and when multiplying matrices M & N say both are a 4x4 matrix: M * N != N * M.

---

When applying Euler Angles of rotation to an object it is based on a specified Axis! This means the object will rotate on its Model's determined axis, based on the Model's origin. If we use a Flight Simulator as an example your three axis of rotations are defined by the terms: Yaw, Pitch and Roll.
The Pitch Rotation would represent the nose of the Jet facing up or down with respect to the Z-Axis and is rotated around the X-axis. The Roll is represented by the tilting of the wings left and right or the Jet doing a side barrel roll. This is with respect to the X-Axis and is rotated around the Z-Axis. The Yaw is complete rotation of the plane in is position, it is relative to the XZ plane and is rotated around the Y-Axis. I could be partially wrong about the Yaw for its been a long time since I worked with these rotations, but the concept doesn't change.

What happens here is the Jet has a continuous velocity applied in a "Forward" motion, When you begin to apply controls to the Jet that enable these 3 different rotations the calculations within the form of Euler Angles are using your basic trig functions such as Sine and Cosine within the Model * View * Projection Matrix applied as Affine Transformations in a linear fashion. The term Gimbal Lock comes from when the Rotations are continuous, your Trig functions that cause the rotation are sinusoidal and due to this when a specific axis rotates to a certain degree two of the 3 axis becomes align, then since two axis are now rotating together you lose the freedom of rotation in one of those dimensions and you are no longer able to rotate against the one that becomes locked. Due to this what happens with the Jet is you will be moving forward and apply a pitch angle that would determine the Jet's height above the ground while the Jet is continuously moving forward, the problem arises within the trig calculations: Eventually when you apply enough Pitch the Plane is now heading in the -vector direction then it was currently heading in, and as you try to continue to rotate, the axis that has become gimbal lock prevents you from rotating the plane on that axis. The same effects can happen with Roll and Yaw as well. To prevent this Quaternions are used.

---

When using Quaternions they are a 4 dimensional vector where each of the elements in the vec4 are defined as ( X-Axis of rotation, Y-Axis of Rotation, Z-Axis of Rotation, Amount of Applied Rotation ) the last component is usually defined as a forth axis that is within the imaginary plane. The applied math on these vectors according to the W component is done within the Imaginary plane! What this does it applies the rotation in the imaginary plane of each of the x,y,z axis, then the translation transformation is then applied. All rotations are for all three axis are done at the same time. This also eliminates the need to rotate the object on each axis separately. This will approximate all the rotations that evaluate to the same Euler Angles preventing Gimbal Lock!

Here are some quick references:

- [Understanding Quaternions](http://www.3dgep.com/understanding-quaternions/)
- [Wiki-Quaternions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation)
- [Wiki-Gimbal Lock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock)
- [YouTube - Gimbal Lock Explained](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zc8b2Jo7mno)
- [Unity Example of Quaternions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TdjoQB43EsQ)
- [YouTube - Quaternions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I0Ge6Qvfg8Y)